# Change screen orientations during monkey run

Tags: android, android-monkey

I'm using monkey command to do some stress testing on my app. But i want to test it more with respect to screen orientations to detect and capture some heapupdates while changing orientations. I searched all over android official site about monkey commands/arguments which will do screen orientations while running on any app/activity. But no luck and thought of asking professionals like you.

If idea on this, please let me know.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?? Can you simplify?

Comment: change orientation using... setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); and setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: I want to rotate the screen orientations while running monkey tests.. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Monkey has a number of undocumented options, including `--pct-rotation`. Add that switch to your command and watch your screen rotate like it's possessed by demons:

Up to (including) adb version 1.0.31:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.example.app -v --pct-rotation=70 500
```

Since adb version 1.0.32:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.example.app -v --pct-rotation 70 500
```

Look in the **processOptions()** method of the monkey command to see all of the supported options: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git/+/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/Monkey.java

Look at the constructor for the **MonkeySourceRandom** class to see the default percentages for all of the event types. These are the current values in the master branch at the time of this post. Note that the default for rotation is 0:

```
    // default values for random distributions
    // note, these are straight percentages, to match user input (cmd line args)
    // but they will be converted to 0..1 values before the main loop runs.
    mFactors[FACTOR_TOUCH] = 15.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_MOTION] = 10.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_TRACKBALL] = 15.0f;
    // Adjust the values if we want to enable rotation by default.
    mFactors[FACTOR_ROTATION] = 0.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_NAV] = 25.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_MAJORNAV] = 15.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_SYSOPS] = 2.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_APPSWITCH] = 2.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_FLIP] = 1.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_ANYTHING] = 13.0f;
    mFactors[FACTOR_PINCHZOOM] = 2.0f;
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git/+/master/cmds/monkey/src/com/android/commands/monkey/MonkeySourceRandom.java

Comment: `--pct-rotation=70` should actually be `--pct-rotation 70`, at least since adb version 1.0.32.

Answer (score 2):

The Test Monkey uses random input. It will change the screen orientation, but there is no guarantee that it will do so on any given test run.

Comment: Yes, there is no way to make sure it will pickup the orientation or not. I wanted to know that whether is it possible to do with exiting monkey tool or not else any other way to do that?

Comment: @user1031345: The Test Monkey *only* uses random input. What you want, by definition, is not random.

Comment: I knew that monkey is random.. All i want is to figure it out on screen orientation changes along with random inputs..

Comment: Are you sure? I did 100000 inputs and zero were rotations.

Comment: @Mgamerz: It's possible they changed the behavior recently, but it most certainly would rotate the screen historically.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no guarantee that Monkey will change orientation during a given run, you can  reach your desired outcome by figuring out a SEED that will cause monkey to change orientation and re-using that SEED in future runs.

```
# monkey -h
usage: monkey [-p ALLOWED_PACKAGE [-p ALLOWED_PACKAGE] ...]
              ...
              [-s SEED] [-v [-v] ...]
              ...
```